# Overriding prototype.toString doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
function Test() {
    this.myTest = "Test";
}

Test.prototype.toString = function testToString() {
    return this.myTest;
};

var test = new Test();
console.log(test);
```

I expect this to print `Test`, but it prints `Test { myTest: 'Test' }`. I thought that overriding `toString` should use that new function whenever it tries to convert to a string. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: `console.log` doesn't necessarily stringify your object - it depends on the environment. Use `console.log(String(test))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

According to the specifications ([console.log](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log) --> [Logger](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) --> [Printer](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer)) the implementation of `console.log` is ultimately up to the implementation.

So, it is likely that in the environment you are working in the implementation of `console.log(obj)` is not simply `Printer("log", obj.toString())`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Test() {
    this.myTest = "Test";
}

Test.prototype.toString = function testToString() {
    return this.myTest;
};

var test = new Test();
console.log(test.toString());
```

Comment: I'm like 99% sure I have seen an example before that doesn't require calling `.toString()` in a console.log like that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the answers here I was able to solve this by using the following code. Although it's similar to some existing answers it is slightly different so decided to post it here.

```
function Test() {
    this.myTest = "Test";
}

Test.prototype.toString = function testToString() {
    return this.myTest;
};

var test = new Test();
console.log(test + "");
```

So just adding `+ ""` to the end of the `console.log` works perfectly and will run the `toString` function.